# setContentsURL related issue

Tags: java, gwt

Hai,

I am using Java GWT. In this  i want to load one html file.

htmlPane.setContentsURL("http://www.chellasoftapp.com/ATBrowser/images/disclaimer.html");

htmlPane.setContentsURL("images/disclaimer.html");

Which one be the faster? How is it works?

In images folder of WAR I placed that html file. Is it correct place? Or Where can i upload this?

Give suggestion for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sathya.A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution:

```
htmlPane.setContentsURL("http://www.chellasoftapp.com/ATBrowser/images/disclaimer.html");
```

has quite big disadventage. It doesn't work in development on local machine.

I would use

```
htmlPane.setContentsURL(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "/images/disclaimer.html");
```

This one always works, doesn't matter if your application is at http://www.chellasoftapp.com/ATBrowser/ or at URL root: http://www.chellasoftapp.com/

Can you put .html file into `images` directory? Yes you can, and technically it is still valid, however, it is not readable and not obvious. I.e. it is hard to understand for other developers.